# iOS: UIView animation, no animating happening

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

Having a puzzling problem. I have a universal app with a lot of shared code between the iPad and iPhone versions. There are different layouts in the nibs but essentially the same views and view hierarchy - one UIView used as a container for two sibling UITextViews.

UIView mainView with children:
UITextView passageTextView
UITextView notesTextView

One UITextView is hidden, the other visible.

The following is my code. The section commented out was my original animation attempt. This worked just as desired on the iPad, but not on the iPhone. The uncommented section is take 2, using the method recommended in the docs. The uncommented code does not work on either the iPad or iPhone - it hides/unhides my views but without any animation. If I add code to the completion block that also gets executed, so it's doing something, just not animating.

```
/*  
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:mainView cache:YES];  

passageTextView.hidden = YES;  
notesTextView.hidden = NO;  

[UIView commitAnimations];  
*/  

UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight;  

[UIView transitionWithView:mainView  
                  duration:1.0  
                   options:options  
                animations:^{ passageTextView.hidden = YES; notesTextView.hidden = NO; }  
                completion:NULL];
```

**Edit**: Still working on the problem, hoping someone has a suggestion.

**Additional update**

Figured out why the following was not working in the iPhone:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];  
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:mainView cache:YES];  

passageTextView.hidden = YES;  
notesTextView.hidden = NO;  

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I had neglected to wire the view to mainView in Interface Builder. Hours debugging and I just now thought to check that.

But, I still do not know why animation blocks are not working for either the iPhone or iPad. I have tried several approaches but I'm not getting any animation even though the show/hides are working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong animation option.

Replace your second animation option by `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` (note the `Option` between `Animation` and `Transition`)

I believe that `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` (which is what you have in your code) is a `UIViewAnimationTransition` not a `UIViewAnimationOptions`.

Comment: I had considered that, but Apple's View Programming Guide section on Animations has an example that uses UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight as an option for UIViewAnimationOptions. In that case, they use transitionFromView:toView: for the animation, but I've tried that method as well with no success.

Comment: But have you actually tried replacing `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` by `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` as I suggest?  I ask because (a) I think it will work and (b) they resolve to different numbers.  UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft resolves to 1 while UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft resolves to 1 << 20.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct. I failed to notice the distinction in your original comment - they are different values and changing to UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft fixed it.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me spending more time on this =)"(&! problem. Was searching more than 2 hours for a solution... I should be more careful when reading the docs.

Comment: I'm trying this exact code with the option and there is no flip transition. The views just get swapped instantly... any suggestions?